# Making an http request with "Accept: text/event-stream" as a header in flutter/dart

Tags: http, dart, flutter, stream

I want to use an API that makes use of [Server Sent Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) protocol. This seems quite simple to handle in a web environment. However, I am struggling to figure out how to do this in Flutter/Dart. Is there a wrapper class/library that I am not seeing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you need this package: https://pub.dev/packages/eventsource

Comment: Thank you @RichardHeap! I can't believe I didn't stumble across that myself. I'll give it a go.

Comment: were you able to get that working?

Comment: I used this package as well and it worked but had some minor issues,  but it seems not really actively supported anymore